# Can't move toolbar item into toolbar menu in Visual Studio customization

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and I really need a menu with useful buttons in the toolbar, now when I got into the customization menu **TOOLS** -> **Customize** -> **Commands**.

[image: Customize -> Commands menu]

I made a custom menu <kbd>"MY_MENU"</kbd> and menu item <kbd>"Close Project"</kbd>, but for some reason I just can't move the menu item into the menu (see picture). How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I had the same problem as the questioner, and managed to solve it, details below.
Note: I use Visual Studio 2015 Professional, but this should apply to later versions as well.

### Scenario

I created a new Toolbar *FooToolBar*, and placed to the toolbars like this:
[image: BarMenu can be seen on the toolbar, next to it, a Solution Explorer icon]

### Goal

To place the "Solution explorer" icon inside the menu.
[image: BarMenu can be seen on the toolbar, next to it, a Solution Explorer icon; an arrow is pointing from the icon towards the menu]

### Problem

Inside the **Customize** window you can't just drag&drop the item to the menu:

[image: Customize window showed]

### Solution

Inside the *Toolbar* combobox, a new item appeared, select that:

[image: Toolbar combobox showing FooToolBar | BarMenu]

After this, you will see a new area where you should place the icon you wanted to.
Also, remove the previous icon from the previous, *FooToolBar* toolbar item.

After doing this, press OK and it will work.

### Result

[image: Image of the tool bar working]

I hope I helped someone. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> **Warning:** After you customize a toolbar or menu, make sure that its check box remains selected in the Customize dialog box. Otherwise, your changes won't persist after you close and reopen Visual Studio.

## [Adding, removing, or moving a menu on the menu bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx#Anchor_0)

1. On the menu bar, choose Tools, Customize.

   The Customize dialog box opens.
2. On the Commands tab, leave the Menu bar option button selected, leave Menu Bar selected in the list next to that option, and then perform one of the following sets of steps:

   [image]

## [Adding, removing, or moving a toolbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx#Anchor_1)

1. On the menu bar, choose Tools, Customize.

   The Customize dialog box opens.
2. On the Toolbar tab, perform one of the following sets of steps:

   To add a toolbar, choose the New button, specify a name for the toolbar that you want to add, and then choose the OK button.

   [image]

## [Customizing a menu or a toolbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx#Anchor_2)

1. On the menu bar, choose Tools, Customize.

   The Customize dialog box opens.
2. On the Commands tab, choose the option button for the type of element that you want to customize.
3. In the list for that type of element, choose the menu or toolbar that you want to customize, and then perform one of the following sets of steps:

   To add a command, choose the Add Command button.

   In the Add Command dialog box, choose an item in the Categories list, choose an item in the Commands list, and then choose the OK button.

[image]

Comment: Great, but this doesn't explain how I actually move my Close project into MY_MENU

Comment: There is no "Options button", The best I can think of is Modify Selection

Comment: Clarified post for ya

Comment: in your second image above you're trying to move a menu into another menu (`Close Project` into `MY_MENU`), not a menu item into a menu.

Comment: Are you saying that "Close_project" is a separate menu? Because then what is a "Menu item"?

Comment: for instance File is a menu and Save As is a menu item.

Comment: How do I add a `Save As` to my menu then?